# How to add hyperlink in meeting body using EWS to c#?

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

How i can add the body information as a hyperlink in EWS meeting?

```
// Create the appointment.
Appointment appointment = new Appointment(service);

// Set properties on the appointment.
appointment.Subject = "Dentist Appointment";
appointment.Body = "The appointment is with Dr. Smith.";
appointment.Start = new DateTime(2009, 3, 1, 9, 0, 0);
appointment.End = appointment.Start.AddHours(2);

// Save the appointment.
appointment.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone);
```

Above code is to create appointment. 
Appointment.Body is having a plain text. How i can make it as a hyperlink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using an HTML fragment for the body:

```
appointment.Body = "The <a href="http://your.link">appointment</a> is with Dr. Smith.";
```

Comment: Thanks man that's working. I haven't tried this simple thing :)